# Solving $x^3 = -1$ for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

How can I solve for the complex solutions of

$$ x^3 = -1 $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use that $$x^3+1=(x+1) \left(x^2-x+1\right)$$